Turn off filtering options by query in AJS.MultiSelect
I create  AJS.MultiSelect with getting options via ajax. I want get options with query by name or by id. And it doesn't work. GroupDescriptor in correct in both cases. It is equal and it has options. But field has options on page only with searching by name, because label of options contains only name. If I concatenate name and id in option's label, searching by id works too. But I don't want to see id in option's label. Is it possible turn off default additional filtering options by query?
new AJS.MultiSelect({
            element: this,
            itemAttrDisplayed: "label",
            showDropdownButton: false,
            ajaxOptions:  {
                data: function (query) {
                    return {
                        query: query,
                        max_results: 20
                    }
                },
                url: AJS.params.baseURL + url,
                query: true,
                minQueryLength: 2,
                formatResponse: formatResponse
            }
        });
    });
}



function formatResponse(data) {
    var ret = [];

    var groupDescriptor = new AJS.GroupDescriptor({
                                    weight: 0,
                                    label: "",
                                    showLabel: false);


    $(data.records).each(function() {
        groupDescriptor.addItem(new AJS.ItemDescriptor({
                            value: this.id,
                            label: this.name
        }));
    });

    ret.push(groupDescriptor);
    return ret;
}

